# How to search a string with spaces and special characters in vi editor

Tags: string, search, vim, special-characters, vi

I edit in the vi editor. I want to search in the text for a specific phrase, e.g `"Dec 1 15:13:00"`. I have tried this search string, but it's not working:

```
/Dec\ 1\ 15
```

How do I search for this string properly? Note that there may be more than one space between the parts.

Comment: It's pretty clear what he's asking for. I had the same question.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open only so that it can be closed with migrated to superuser.

Answer (score 32):

Numbers and spaces are not special characters so

```
 /Dec 1 15
```

is enough.

Generally speaking special characters are escaped with a `\`. For example, if you search for `Dec.`, you should type `/Dec\.`

If you are using Vim, you might also want to check

```
:help pattern.txt
```

And specifically the `magic` chapter.

If you want to know if magic is set, type `:set magic?`

The magic option can change the behavior of pattern matching.

Comment: /Dec 1 15 not working ,E486: Pattern not found: Dec 1 15

Comment: @user5628973: you might have multiple spaces which would make the search fails. Try to play around because it should work.

Comment: How can we exclude the multiple space?

Comment: @user5628973: /Dec[ ]*1 could work. (this work in my vim setup but I am not very familiar with the difference between vim and pure vi.

Comment: @user5628973 if this answers your question, can you please accept it? Thanks!